# Extract value preceeded by a certain word in c++ output

Tags: c++, string, output, ifstream

If you have a file with a text of known structure how would you extract a value preceeded by certain identifying word? Specifically, how do you extract the value from the piece of text below.

```
CDM-nucleon micrOMEGAs amplitudes:
proton:  SI  -3.443E-10
```

Here is how far I got with the script:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string identifier;
double value;
ifstream file("output.txt");
// Commands to extract value
file.close();

return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: No one will do the work for you. Especially when your question is so unclear. Extract what? What is the identifing word? What have you done and where is the problem. Search stackoverflow to figure out how to read a file line by line and how to use regex to find a position. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity and size of the output file. By 'complexity' I mean, say, a possibility to find your identifying word not followed by a number and variety of keywords you want to parse.
For a big file it may be unreasonable to load it into the memory, hence possible streaming.

In your particular case, you may want to look into this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

or one of the parsers suitable for streamed data:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser

You might also look into other languages such as perl to parse that.